# I am trying to take the values from this form and insert it into a table using mysql and node JS, but unable to get the value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying got take the value that is inserted into the first and last name fields and then take that and insert it into a MySQL database backend that I have running using restAPI. What am I missing so that the first name and last name are actually converted into [firstname] and [lastname] that will be used in the MySql script

The table code is this

```
  <div class="superhero">
    <h1>Lets add our first name </h1>
    <form action="/add_user" method="post">
        <input type = "text" firstname = "firstname">
    <h1>Lets add our last name </h1>
    <form action="/add_user" method="post">
        <input type = "text" lastname = "lastname">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

Then this is taken into the nodeJS server with this command

```
app.post('/add_people', function(req, res){
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser')
    .then((response)=>{
        var restlist = response.data.results;
        console.log(restlist);
// Now we will execute the results in the page named thanks
    });
});
```

Then at the end it is going to be taken to the RestAPI with that is using this route

```
@app.route('/api/adduser', methods = ['POST']) # This is a post method because the user needs to be able to add info
def adding_stuff():
    request_data = request.get_json() # Gets the info from the table and converts to JSON format
    new_fname = request_data['firstname']
    new_lname = request_data['lastname']
    conn = create_connection("", "", "", "")
    sql = "INSERT INTO restaurantusers (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('%s', '%s');" % (new_fname, new_lname) # This sql statement will then be uploaded to the databse to add a new record
    execute_query(conn, sql) # This will execute the query
    return 'Post worked'
```

Sorry if what I am asking sounds really complicated. Professor goes too fast in class and I've been trying to find out how to do this for sometime with no luck.

UDATE: I later changed the two items as suggested. The route is

```
app.post('/add_people', function(req, res){
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser')
    .then((response)=>{
        var restlist = response.data.results;
        console.log(restlist);
// Now we will execute the results in the page named thanks
    });
});
```

and the form is now

```
        <form action="/add_people" method="post">
            <input type = "text" firstname = "firstname">
        <h1>Lets add our last name </h1>
            <input type = "text" lastname = "lastname">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
```

I get the error that

```
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

and also this error on the restAPI window

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: In addition to the answer, you're making a `GET` call to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser` but your 3rd code snippet has `/api/adduser` annotated as a POST method.
When you make your `POST` request in `axios`, you'll need to specify the data from the form (you can use the `req` object for this).

Comment: ok thank you, I am going to work rn and ill adjust it later and hope that works! thanks

Comment: I actually updated the code and edited the post to show the error that I got. if I want to log the response do I have to add axis.get right after axis.post?

Comment: you can check response of you http post request. If you make another one, like get it will be separate independent request.

Comment: I get this error
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}

Comment: then an error that said my browser cannot open the page

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two mistakes in the form.

1. You don't need to break first and last name in two separate forms.
2. The route `add_user` doesn't match your post route.

You might need to make these changes

```
 <div class="superhero">
    <h1>Lets add our first name </h1>
    <form action="/api/adduser" method="post">
        <input type = "text" firstname = "firstname">
    <h1>Lets add our last name </h1>
        <input type = "text" lastname = "lastname">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

Comment: I get this error when I made the change to the form. It is the same error I got as before

Comment: You are not sending data in post request ` axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/adduser', body)`. Please add body to the post request, without sending body you can't expect correct o/p.

Comment: Ok, what does the body part do? sorry still new to this. Because it says that body is not defined. Is that and body parser the same